# Getting small pulses on the output of an AND port, even though inputs are always low

Tags: digital-logic, noise

I am building circuit and in that circuit, I have an AND port (7408). When using a logic analyzer, measuring both inputs (on 24 MHz) they stay low.

However, when measuring the output, I see some noise. Never longer that the sampling time though (24 MHz, so ~42ns).

Is there a reason for this, and how could I prevent / mitigate this? The pulses on the output are used as a clock signal, so the receiving end is getting more clocks than I want.

Comment: I am an idiot. I had not connected the ground of the logic analyzer.

Answer (score 1):

If the inputs are truly stable and low, then you are probably seeing spikes on the ground pin of the 7408. It is also possible that you have noise on the power line, but if you only see positive spikes I would suspect the ground connections.

Be sure to have a bypass capacitor directly at the power and ground of all of your logic devices, and distribute power and ground with short fat wires.

Answer (score 1):

The grounds on low cost logic analyzers are inadequate in many circumstances and can either pick-up noise or in-particular get interaction between channels.

For example a transition on one channel can also be seen on other channels just for single sample. This is caused by signal current flowing through the common ground lead.

Are any other channels changing at the same time?

Try disconnecting all but the one channel with the problem and see if that cures the issue.